# Akka simple cluster example

Tags: akka

I am new to Akka. I am trying the first cluster example in Akka Java Doc. The codes are as follows:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.cluster.Cluster;
import akka.cluster.ClusterEvent.ClusterDomainEvent;

public class SimpleClusterApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Override the configuration of the port
    // when specified as program argument
    if (args.length > 0)
        System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port", args[0]);

    // Create an Akka system
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem");

    // Create an actor that handles cluster domain events
    ActorRef clusterListener = system.actorOf(Props.create(SimpleClusterListener.class), "clusterListener");

    // Add subscription of cluster events
    Cluster.get(system).subscribe(clusterListener, ClusterDomainEvent.class);
}
}
```

But it cannot work. Eclipse complains that the SimpleClusterListener.class cannot be resolved. Could anyone tell me how can I find this class?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/java/cluster-usage.html:

The Akka cluster is a separate jar file. Make sure that you have the following [Maven] dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
  <artifactId>akka-cluster_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The full source isn't included in the documentation (that I can see, anyway).

But it is in the Git Repository: https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-cluster-java/src/main/java/sample/cluster/simple

Hope that helps :)